# How to use Typescript scripts with Electron?

Tags: typescript, electron

I am building a rudimentary electron app, in which I want to reference a script with

```
    <script src="build/script.js"></script>
```

I do have a `script.ts` file, which compiles to `build` folder

```
import { dialog } from 'electron'

const openFileLocationDialog = () => {
  dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile'] })
}

const sourceButton = document.getElementById('button') 
sourceButton!.addEventListener('click', openFileLocationDialog)
```

However when I run the app, I get the error

```
script.ts:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at script.ts:1
```

Even though `script.ts` isn't referenced anywhere.

What's the course of action here? All I really want is to have a button to select a file.

Comment: How are you compiling to the build directory? What does your tsconfig look like?

Comment: ```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "./build",
      "strict": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the library exported in a web compatible format, not nodeJS (cjs) format, because the error basically says it doesn't know how to `require`.

This is not exactly a electron question, if you just create a `index.html` and put your script there, you will get the same error.